# viewWillTransitionToSize の中で safeAreaInsets を取得する方法

Tags: swift, ios, iphone-x

`viewWillTransition(to size: with coordinator:)`メソッドのiPhoneX対応を試みています。 回転後のsefeAreaInsetsの値の取得をしたいのですが、方法がわかりません。宜しくお願いします。

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize,
        with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow { 
            let insets = window.safeAreaInsets
            contentFrame = CGRect(x:insets.left, y:insets.top,
            width:size.width - insets.left - insets.right,
            height:size.height - insets.top - insets.bottom)
        }
    } else {
        contentFrame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:size.width, height:size.height)
    }
    self.updateViews()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

下記のように、`UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator.animate(alongsideTransition:completion:)`のクロージャの中で`sefeAreaInsets`を取得します。その時の値は回転した後の値になります。

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (context) in
        ...

        let insets = ...safeAreaInsets

        ...
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: 有難うございました。これで無事にiPhoneX対応ができそうです！

Comment: Stackoverflow英語版の方にも転載させて頂きます。